# Bijection between closed unit interval and $ R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there any bijection between closed unit interval and $R$?

Comment: There are many of them, but none of them are continuous. What have you tried?

Comment: A little off topic, but your offhand remark has a neat idea behind it. At first I would expect there to be continuous bijections which are not homeomorphisms (indeed, this can be done for non-compact closed sets). But because the closed unit interval is compact, any continuous image of it must also be compact and in particular cannot be $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because they both have the cardinality of the continuum.